# How to get props in Nav

Tags: reactjs

I try to get props in Nav but always get {} empty object, how can I resolve this problem?

I try to pass props from App.js but again I get {} empty.

```
   <Nav/> // this is Nav
        <Switch>
                        <Redirect from="/" exenter code hereact to="/login" />
                        <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
                        <ProtectedRoute path="/home" exact component={Home} />
                        <ProtectedRoute path="/about" exact component={About} />
                        <ProtectedRoute path="/contact" exact component={Contact} />
                        <ProtectedRoute
                          path="/contact/:id"
                          exact
                          component={ContactDetails}
                        />
                        <Redirect from="*" to="/" />
                      </Switch>
```

Comment: Can you show code of Nav not its parent

Comment: you are not passing any props to nav.

Comment: class Nav extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={rtDv}>
          HEADER
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              userService.logout(() => {
                console.log(this.props);
                this.props.history.push("/home");
              });
            }}
          >
            Logout
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Your component:

```
class Nav extends Component { 
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props); 
  } 

render() { 
  return ( 
    <div> 
      <div style={rtDv}> HEADER 
        <button onClick={() => { 
          userService.logout(() => { console.log(this.props); 
          this.props.history.push("/home"); }); 
          }
        } 
        > Logout 
      </button> 
      </div> 
     </div> 
     ); 
  } 
}
```

To send props inside it, you should do in another component:

```
<Nav
   propsName={value}
   propsName2={value2}
/>
```

And use it in the component with this.props.propsName etc...